# Can you push to a dynamically declared array in Angular with $parse?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I would like to use `$parse` in angularJS to dynamically create a scope variable which references an array and then `push` to that array; but `$parse`'s `assign` method does not seem to do the trick.

```
$scope.life.meaning = [];

var the_string = 'life.meaning';

// Get the model
var model = $parse(the_string);
```

Would like to push '42' into the array. So the following won't work:

```
// Assigns a value to it
model.assign($scope, 42);
```

Are there any other ways to do this? Thanks.

Comment: `$scope.life.meaning.push(42)`

Comment: Thank you but it's dynamically declared so if used in a directive you would not know the value of ```the_string``` until it is declared programmatically. I just wrote ```$scope.life.meaning = []``` so it was clear it would always reference an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example is overwriting the assignment for that object on the scope. The $parse can be used to either get or make assignments. What you need to do it get the array and then push the item onto the array that you got. Because JavaScript arrays are pointers in memory, adding to the array that you retrieved will do the trick.

```
//get the current value as evaluated against the $scope
var ar = $parse('life.meaning')($scope);

//if the value isn't an array then make it one
if (!Array.isArray(ar)) {
    ar = [];
    $parse('life.meaning').assign($scope, ar);
}

//add an item to the array
ar.push(42);
```

Comment: Genius answer. Thanks :-D